# how to take screenshots of a program running on linux?

Tags: linux, xserver

Is there anyway to capture the display(take screenshots for every x seconds) of a program like we can capture the std::out and std::err by $ program > a.txt

Note: 
1. I don't want to use gnome-screenshot as I need to screenshot of multiple programs simultaneously.
2. I also don't want the programs GUI to be shown in the display

Comment: Well, what **do** you want to be shown in the display?

Comment: Nothing related to the program

Comment: So what you want is a software recommendation for a program that can capture a screenshot from your active terminal emulator window and nothing else? If that really is the case, your question seems to have fairly little to do with the [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on SO.